# Create dynamic thunk and extra reducer for multiple API calling and fetch data

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, redux-toolkit

I am using Redux and Redux-Toolkit and want to use a single asynchronous Thunk and single extra reducer for multiple requests.

Here is my companies slice:

```js
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import axios from 'axios'

const initialState = {
  data: {
    companys: []
  },
  loading: false,
  isError: false,
}

export const getCompanyThunk = createAsyncThunk(
  "companyThunk",
  async ({ url, method }) => {
    const res = await axios({
      method: method,
      url: url,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": localStorage.getItem("token")
      }
    })
    return res.data;
  }
)

export const companySlice = createSlice({
  name: 'companys',
  initialState,
  reducer: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(getCompanyThunk.pending, (state) => {
      state.loading = true;
    });
    builder.addCase(getCompanyThunk.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.isError = false;
      state.data.companys = action.payload
    });
    builder.addCase(getCompanyThunk.rejected, (state) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.isError = true;
    });
  }
})

export const companyReducer = companySlice.reducer
```

And here is my client slice

```js
import { createSlice, createAsyncThunk } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import axios from 'axios'

const initialState = {
  data: {
    client: [],
  },
  loading: false,
  isError: false,
}

export const getClientThunk = createAsyncThunk(
  "clientThunk",
  async ({ url, method }) => {
    const res = await axios({
      method: method,
      url: url,
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        "Authorization": localStorage.getItem("token")
      }
    })
    return res.data;
  }
)

export const clientSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'client',
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(getClientThunk.pending, (state) => {
      state.loading = true;
    });
    builder.addCase(getClientThunk.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.isError = false;
      state.data.client = action.payload
    });
    builder.addCase(getClientThunk.rejected, (state) => {
      state.loading = false;
      state.isError = true;
    });
  }
})

export const clientReducer = clientSlice.reducer
```

Look there is multiple lines of code are repeated I want use single `createAsyncThunk` and `extraReducer` but problem is every thunk have different name so I don't use that thunk multiple time and when I do that then it has unexpected behaviour .

Here is my API call for both slices

```js
useEffect(() => {
  const requestOptions = {
    url: "http://localhost:3333/companys",
    method: "GET",
  }
  dispatch(getCompanyThunk(requestOptions))
}, [])
```

And for clientData

```js
const handleCompanyChange = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const requestOptions = {
    url: `http://localhost:3333/getClients/${e.target.value}`,
    method: 'GET',
  }
  dispatch(getClientThunk(requestOptions))
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These two state slices and thunks really only seem to differ on the "state" they ultimately result in updating. You could merge them into a single state slice with the data for each, using a "key" to specify if the state that is being fetched or updated is "companies" or "client" etc.

Example:

```js
const initialState = {
  client: {
    data: [],
    loading: false,
    isError: false
  },
  companies: {
    data: [],
    loading: false,
    isError: false
  }
};

const getClientCompaniesThunk = createAsyncThunk(
  "clientCompanysThunk",
  async ({ url, method }, thunkApi) => {
    try {
      const { data } = await axios({
        method,
        url,
        headers: {
          "Content-Type": "application/json",
          Authorization: localStorage.getItem("token")
        }
      });

      return data;
    } catch (error) {
      return thunkApi.rejectWithError(error);
    }
  }
);

const clientCompaniesSlice = createSlice({
  name: "client",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addCase(getClientCompaniesThunk.pending, (state, action) => {
      state[action.meta.arg.key].loading = true;
    });
    builder.addCase(getClientCompaniesThunk.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
      state[action.meta.arg.key].loading = false;
      state[action.meta.arg.key].isError = false;
      state[action.meta.arg.key].data = action.payload;
    });
    builder.addCase(getClientCompaniesThunk.rejected, (state, action) => {
      state[action.meta.arg.key].loading = false;
      state[action.meta.arg.key].isError = action.payload;
    });
  }
});
```

```js
export const store = configureStore({
  reducer: clientCompaniesSlice.reducer
});
```

Usage:

```js
const companies = useSelector((state) => state.companies);
const client = useSelector((state) => state.client);

...

useEffect(() => {
  const requestOptions = {
    key: "companies",
    url: "http://localhost:3333/companies",
    method: "GET"
  };
  dispatch(getClientCompaniesThunk(requestOptions));
}, [dispatch]);

const handleCompanyChange = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const requestOptions = {
    key: "client",
    url: `http://localhost:3333/getClients/${e.target.value}`,
    method: "GET"
  };
  dispatch(getClientCompaniesThunk(requestOptions));
};

...
```

### Demo

Here's a demo using "users" and "posts" in place of "companies" and "client" with regards to state and mocked fetched JSON data.

[image: Edit create-dynamic-thunk-and-extra-reducer-for-multiple-api-calling-and-fetch-data]

An optimization/improvement here may be to use [Redux-Toolkit Query](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/overview) and implement an [API slice](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/createApi) instead and declare these as two query endpoints. The UI can simply use one of the auto-generated React hooks (*e.g. [lazy query](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/hooks#uselazyquery) in this specific case*) to query for the data via a callback function in the `useEffect` hook and `handleCompanyChange` `onChange` handler.

Comment: I tried it out but i guess it may give problem in production so I can't use this solution

Comment: @MohanDhila What is the concern in production? What sort of different solution are you looking for?